# phpmyadmin shows error double increment with two column not possible

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I tried to make these following two tables with phpmyadmin.

```
create table category (
catId int identity(1,1),
catName varchar(20),

Constraint pk_category
PRIMARY KEY(catId))

create table subcategory (
subCatId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
catId INT,
subCatName VARCHAR(20),

CONSTRAINT pk_subcategory
PRIMARY KEY(catId,subCatId),

CONSTRAINT fk_subcat_cat
FOREIGN KEY(catID)
REFERENCES category(catId))
```

When creating the subcategory it shows this query error:

## 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key .

There aren't two auto incremented columns in subcategory table, only the 'subCatId' is. What should be done?

Comment: Either you'll have to make the `subCatId ` as `PK` or make it as `Unique`. Because that is an `Auto increment` column.

Comment: What happens if  the catId and subcatId takes both same values? I mean if catId = 1 and subcatId = 1 ?

Comment: yes now it works I changed subcatId field to 'auto_increment unique'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what MySQL states

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be
>   indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. An AUTO_INCREMENT column
>   works properly only if it contains only positive values. Inserting a
>   negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number.
>   This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers “wrap” over from
>   positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally
>   get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.

So according to your requirement you've following choices.

- Make `subCatId` as `Primary Key`
- Or Make the column as `Unique`

Answer (score 2):

> It is only available for the MyISAM Storage Engine Only one numeric
>   auto_increment value is allowed. Each auto_increment must be have
>   associated column to define uniqueness from other auto_increment
>   values within the same table.

This ref link may hep you more about [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/).

> **Note:**
>   Don't do that, don't have a second auto incremented column at all. Do you really need a second auto incremented value? What for? A
>   description of the actual problem you are trying to solve would help
>   others help you better. I think you have only told here how you tried
>   to solve a problem and not what the actual problem is.

Comment: No the upper table's (category table) catId set to auto_increment. So I do not want subcategory table's catId to be auto_increment. But phpmyadmin takes both columns as auto incremented when creating second table.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using SQL Server syntax, but run against MySQL.  Use the correct syntax and it should work:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    catId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    catName VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (catId)
)

CREATE TABLE subcategory (
    subCatId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    catId INT,
    subCatName VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (catId) REFERENCES category (catId),
    PRIMARY KEY (subCatId)
);
```

`IDENTITY` in SQL Server roughly corresponds to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Comment: Yes  I used auto_increment like said but still the error shows up.

Comment: [My code is working completely fine in this demo](https://rextester.com/JLJX20485).  You have some other problem(s) with your code.

Comment: I changed the line 'subcatId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,' to 'subcatId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,' now it work.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Constraint pk_category
PRIMARY KEY(catId)
```

Instead, just say

```
PRIMARY KEY(catId)
```

Comment: constraints should have unique names to identify shouldn't they?

Comment: The default name for the PK is `PRIMARY`.  The keyword `CONSTRAINT` is nowhere needed in MySQL; a name can be provided.

Comment: OK I was handling with mssql earlier.

Comment: Would only 'PRIMARY' enough to declare pk?

Comment: @LizardKing_96 - `PRIMARY` gets a syntax error; it needs `PRIMARY KEY`.  Note:  In MySQL, a PK is, by definition, clustered, unique, and an index.